# How to migrate VirtualBox 2 virtual computer to VmWare server2?

Tags: vmware-server, virtualization, migration, virtualbox

How to migrate VirtualBox 2 virtual computer (virtual drive) to VmWare Server 2? Computer itself runs Linux, virtual computers run Windows XP and Windows Vista. I need support for GRE protocol, which is not done in VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may [this](http://dossy.org/2008/05/migrating-from-virtualbox-to-vmware/) will help.

Comment: Link-only answers are "Not An Answer" in Stack Exchange because if the link dies, then the entire post is rendered useless.  This would be more suitable as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a VirtualBox image to VMWare using QEMU (aptitude install qemu) command:

```
qemu-img convert vb_hd.vdi -O vmdk vmware_hd.vmdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note - vmware alone probably won't solve the problem.
The problem is you're using NAT instead of bridging. We have problems in both vmware and virtualbox using NAT mode. GRE works fine in virtualbox and vmware using bridge mode networking. A quick web search shows others still having problems with GRE using vmware in NAT mode.

We use VPN's on bridged virtualbox clients daily with no issues.